# blur effect of UIVisualEffect is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have an ImageView that I want to apply blurEffect on it. I tried doing it from storyboard and programmatically but it's still not working . it's keep showing gray solid background.

I saw many videos on Youtube and many tutorials on the internet but still the same!

this is the code that I'm using right now.

```
       view.addSubview(imageView)
       let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.light)
       let blureView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
       blureView.frame = view.bounds
       view.addSubview(blureView)
```

and here what I'm getting

[image]

Comment: Does `imageView` have an image set? The blur view code looks fine

Comment: @aheze yes it has. I don't know what is going on . I tried doing it from storyboard and still the same . even changed the style of blur effect and nothing works

Comment: Do you have the project on GitHub? I can take a look at it if you want

Comment: @aheze well, don't have it on GitHub . I can send you any code you want to check it. I just don't understand why it's not working with me while it's work fine with others with the same code

Comment: Hmm ok. In which method are you putting the above code? viewDidLoad?

Comment: Also, what is the `frame` of `imageView`? Try printing it out.

Comment: yes in viewDidLoad . the same frame of visualEffect . which cover the whole ViewController